# How to determine the nature of a series

Tags: divergent-series

Consider the following series :$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin (n)\cos (\frac{1}{n})}}{{\sqrt {n + 2} }}} 
$$

We want to determine if the series diverges or not.

I tried so far using the small-angle approximation for the cosine, but it turned even messier. Is this problem as tough as I see it, or is it there something obvious that I'm overlooking ? 
If anyone gets any ideas towards a solution I would be most welcome!

Comment: What is your goal here? Are you trying to sum the series or just establish convergence?

Comment: Just establish convergence, sorry for not being explicit

Answer (score 2):

The partial sums of [$\sin(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986835/finding-the-sum-of-sin0-circ-sin1-circ-sin2-circ-cdots-sin/986860#986860) are bounded. The sequence $\cos(1/n)/\sqrt{n+2}$ goes to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$. A more general version of the alternating series test then tells us that this series converges conditionally.

Comment: Boundedness of partial sums of $\sin n$ needs some clarification, but +1.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't want to get into the details. There is enough here that the OP or someone else can fill in the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Well the small angle approximation gives $\cos{\frac{1}{n}} = 1 + O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ so
$$\frac{\sin{n}\cos{n}}{\sqrt{n+2}} = \frac{\sin{n}}{\sqrt{n+2}} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
Since the series of $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ is absolutely convergent, it only remains to study
$$ \sum \frac{\sin{n}}{\sqrt{n+2}} $$
Now it is time to use some standard techniques/criteria...