# Finding summation of series by inspection.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been trying to find out how the summation is deduced via inspection. However, it is to no avail.

[image]

Could anyone show me a way to quickly deduce this form? Thanks.

Comment: Why the giant font?

Comment: See my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986835/finding-the-sum-of-sin0-circ-sin1-circ-sin2-circ-cdots-sin/986860#986860 , a similar method will work here. There isn't a way to just see the result as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\pi  ( 2t-0.5 )$

then $\displaystyle \sum_{k=-9}^{9} e^{-ikx} =  e^{9ix} \sum_{k=0}^{18} e^{-ikx} $

Now use the formula for the sum of a geometric series ...

$\displaystyle = e^{9ix} \frac{e^{- 19 i x} -1}{e^{ - i x} -1} $

which simplifies to

$\displaystyle =  \frac{e^{-10 i x} - e^{9ix}}{e^{ i x} -1}$

$\displaystyle = \frac{ e^{-ix/2} ( e^{-(19/2)  i x} - e^{(19/2)ix} ) }{ e^{-i x/2}( e^{ -i x/2} -e^{ i x/2} ) } $

$\displaystyle = \frac{ e^{-(19/2)  i x} - e^{(19/2)ix}  }{ e^{ -i x/2} -e^{ i x/2}  }  = \frac{sin(\frac{19x}{2}) }{sin(\frac{x}{2}) }$