# Sine representation of cosine

Tags: power-series, fourier-series

I am trying to establish the following partial sum equivalence:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos (n\pi u) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\sin(N+\frac{1}{2})\pi u}{\sin(\pi u)/2} - 1\right]$$

with a hint that the series
$$x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots x^m= \frac{1-x^{m+1}}{1-x}$$

My approach is to represent
$$\cos(n\pi u) = \frac{1}{2}\left[e^{in\pi u} + e^{-in\pi u}\right]$$
and then letting $x = e^{i\pi u}$ I can reduce this to
$$\cos(n\pi u) = \frac{1}{2}\left[x + x^2 + \ldots x^{N} + x^{-1} + x^{-2} + \ldots x^{-N}\right]$$
Now, I notice that the first and last terms sum to
$$x + \frac{1}{x^N} = \frac{x^N + 1}{x^N}$$
likewise, the second and the second-to-last sum to
$$x^2 + \frac{1}{x^{N-1}} = \frac{x^N + 1}{x^{N-1}}$$
so that the first sum is $x$ multiplied by the second. Now let
$$a = \frac{1 + x^N}{x^N}$$
and we reduce this series to
$$\cos(n\pi u) = \frac{1}{2}\left[a\left(1 + x + x^2 + \ldots x^{N-1}\right)\right]$$
which is equivalent to
$$a\left[\frac{x}{1-x}\right]$$
Then, using the value of $a$, I get
$$\cos(n\pi u) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{x^2}{1-x}\right]$$

I am, however, not sure if I have proceeded in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: It isn't $\cos(\pi u)$ that is equal to that sum of powers of $x$, it is the **sum** of the cosines, i;e; the expression you are trying to evaluate. What I would do next is add $1$ to the sum, we get two geometric series. Sum them with the finite geometric series formula. At the end (peek at the formula on the right) you will be subtracting that $1$ you just added.

Comment: See the method I applied in my answer here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986835/finding-the-sum-of-sin0-circ-sin1-circ-sin2-circ-cdots-sin/986860#986860

Comment: consider $$\bigg(\sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{i\pi nu}\bigg) -1$$ and use the geometric sum formula

Comment: I appreciate this hint very much, I was able to solve it using this, and liberal doses of Wolfram Alpha for trig identities. Thanks for the idea!